# Are there Karma thresholds on Launchpad for gaining access to certain features

Tags: development, launchpad

I'm currently reviewing bus on Launchpad and the option to Triage them is greyed out for me. Is this because my Karma is not high enough (599 at time of writing) or is it because I'm not a part of the correct team (I'm working on papercuts).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, Launchpad karma has no bearing on what you can access.

The "Triaged" and "Won't Fix" bug statuses are reserved to the role called the "[bug supervisor](https://help.launchpad.net/Bugs/YourProject#Bug%20supervisors%20and%20security%20contacts)" for each project or distribution. For Ubuntu, this is the [Ubuntu Bugs](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-bugs) team (actually, effectively, the [Ubuntu Bug Control](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-bugcontrol) team), which you have to be part of in order to set the statuses in question.

You can [join Ubuntu Bug Control](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBugControl) once you've spent some time triaging bugs and have familiarized yourself with the various triage procedures.

Comment: People have suggested that using karma to gate access to some Launchpad features would be a good idea, but there hasn't been extensive discussion of that I'm aware of.

Comment: I think the only discussion I've seen along those lines has been the odd suggestion to limit things to accounts with non-zero karma, as a "this account has done something useful and isn't entirely new" test.  But indeed, LP is not like StackExchange ...

Comment: and it's possible to exploit the karma system to get a high score without actually contributing much

Comment: This may be outdated now, based on https://askubuntu.com/questions/951773/what-can-i-do-when-launchpad-shows-a-wrong-upstream-connection/1377830#1377830 which indicated that there is at least one permission which is gated, but I don't yet whether karma is the key to unlock that permission